# vcruntime.h missing from Windows include folder?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm a beginner and I'm trying to build an open source project for the first time in Windows, but I keep running into `file not found` errors when building. What I've found so far is that a header file called `corecrt.h` is located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\`. This file would include another header file named `vcruntime.h`. The problem is that `vcruntime.h` is nowhere to be found in that folder.

I later found that `vcruntime.h` is located in a separate folder located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include`. This is strange because I'm not sure why `corecrt.h` would include a file that is not in its own filepath...

I did the bone-headed thing of just copying over `vcruntime.h` file to the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\`, but this just shifts the problem down the road because `vcruntime.h` in turn also includes other header files located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include`, and so on.

I think the issue lies with Windows itself. I think I'm missing something that's suppose to install additional header files like `vcruntime.h` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\`

So far I've tried uninstalling/reinstalling Windows SDK, and just reinstall Windows as a whole, but still no dice to make the missing files appear in that folder. Can someone give me some insight on this? I've asked this question on Reddit but so far nothing has been able to help.

Here's the link to the instructions I'm following on how to build https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Development/BuildingOnWindows

I'm building using their suggested environment Lode on my Windows 10 machine.

I get `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt.h(10): error: vcruntime.h: No such file or directory`

The error occurs right at the build step and I run `make 2>&1 | tee build.log`

Comment: The directories where you found those headers look right, but if the compiler doesn't find them it means the "include" path is not set correctly. This is a matter of project or makefile or perhaps command line you are using, but it's hard to tell without more details about what you are attempting to build and how exactly.

Comment: It's for LibreOffice. Here's the link to the instructions https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Development/BuildingOnWindows

Comment: That page describes several ways to build different parts in different configurations. Please edit your question and specify what your setup is, what you are trying to build and the exact error message(s) at which step.

Comment: yes, this files in different locations corecrt.h - inside ucrt in sdk, vcruntime in vc crt. nothing need copy or reinstall. but ser correct paths in vs or per project

Comment: @dxiv Done. I updated the OP

Comment: Try running the build from a Visual Studio command prompt (not your regular command prompt), unless you're doing that already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too had the same issue, but found the cause which was the Include directories were not specified correctly.  To fix this I did the following with Visual Studio:

1. Right click on the project name, and then click on **Properties**.
2. Under Configuration Properties, select **VC++ Directories**.
3. The Include directories should contain **$(VC_IncludePath);$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath);** - correct this.
4. Click OK to save and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: This did not work for me.

Comment: This did not work for me either on vs2022

Answer (score 0):

You most likely use cygwin for make. The source of the issue is that linux is getting a nightmare when you have spaces in path names, so they are being converted to Windows 8.3 format, like C:/PROGRA~2/.

In your particular case, after autogen.sh created config_host.mk file, check SOLARINC variable in it. It should only contain Windows 8.3 path names, like `-IC:/PROGRA~2/`, no cygdrive.

Answer (score -1):

I too had the same issue in Visual Studio 2019 when compiling a legacy project from an older version of Visual Studio. Solved the following way:

1. Right click on the project name, and then click on **Properties**.
2. Under Configuration Properties, select **General**.
3. Switch **Platform Toolset** to the latest version.