# C++ compilation error on visual studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I am using visual studio 2008 due to some compatibility issues, i am getting the following error while building my project -

**fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'vcruntime.h' : No such file or directory.**
I even installed Windows sdk and included the path in my workstation but this error is just taking my time, oit has been almost a day now, i even tried to search this 'vcruntime.h' but its not present in my system

i would love to here some suggestions,

tried installing windows sdk and added to my projects path but not working

Comment: The way to solve compatibility issues, is to update to **modern** compilers. Clearly your current attempt to solve your compatibility issue has not worked.

Comment: The manual of this system specifically mentioned VS2008 to be used to build this project. That's the reason i am using VS2008.

Comment: Presumably then you have the wrong SDK installed, or you have multiple SDKs installed and are including a mix of header files. Perhaps one thing to try would be an install of VS 2008 on a clean machine.

Comment: one possibility would have been that the file 'vcruntime.h' is present somewhere on the machine but the IDE is not able to find it while building the solution.
in which case this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62616834/vcruntime-h-missing-from-windows-include-folder) would have helped.

Comment: But that is ruled out as you already mentioned that the file is nowherer to be found. 
So, the next possibility is that the right version of VC++ redistributable is not installed on the machine.
Depending on which version of Visual Studio 2008 is being used, installing the related VC++ redistributable version can solve this issue.
For instance if Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1 is being used then the VC++ redistributable can be found here:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26368